# How to make Python's findall regular expression method inclusive

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a string that looks as follows.

`s = 'string with %%substring1%% and %%substring2%%'`

I want to extract the text in the substrings *including the `%%`* and I cannot figure out how to make a regular expression inclusive.

For example, `re.findall('%%(.*?)%%', s, re.DOTALL)` will output `['substring1', 'substring2']`, but what I really want is for it to return `['%%substring1%%', '%%substring2%%']`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were quite near. Put the group to match the entire required portion rather than only the string in between

```
>>> s = 'string with %%substring1%% and %%substring2%%'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('(%%.*?%%)', s, re.DOTALL)
['%%substring1%%', '%%substring2%%']
```

You actually do not need the parens at all!

```
>>> re.findall('%%.*?%%', s, re.DOTALL) # Even this works !!! 
['%%substring1%%', '%%substring2%%']
```

And for some visualization, check this out

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/HFb9DVAVtl2UTXz_)

And check the explaination [here](https://regex101.com/r/bQ6pA5/1#python)

Comment: you dont even need the parentheses since it return the complete match in the absense of parens :P (+1 all the same :P)

Comment: @JoranBeasley True that!

Comment: My 400th post on SO! Pat on my own back